# Using MGF's to find sampling distribution of estimator for population mean

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

In the following question a sample of random variables are given that are independent and identically distributed whereby $X_1, ..., X_n \sim f_X$. It can be assumed that the random sample is from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ population.

An estimator for the population mean is given as
$$\hat{\mu}_n = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$

We are asked to use moment generating functions to define the sample distribution of $\hat{\mu}_n$

I know that the MGF for a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is 
$$M(t)=\exp(\mu t+ \frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2})$$

Is it simply a matter of taking the formula for the estimator $\hat{\mu}_n = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for $\mu$ and calculating the variance of the estimator and plugging both of those  into the formula for $M(t)$ and simplifying?

Sorry, not sure if I'm on the right track. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Calculate $E[e^{t\hat\mu_n}]$ where you will require the MGF $M(t)$ on simplification.

Comment: Thanks for the initial tip. That got me on my way to getting the answer. When I understood that $e^{t \hat{\mu}_n} = (M(\frac{t}{n-1}))^n$ I was on my way.  thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed strategy assumes $\hat{\mu}_n$ is Normal, which you might know already, but it's often proved by computing its MGF, which is the point of the problem. So a solution that requires less prior knowledge notes$$\Bbb E^{t\hat{\mu}_n}=M_{X_1}^n(t/(n-1))=\exp\left(\frac{n\mu t}{n-1}+\frac{n\sigma^2t^2}{2(n-1)^2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks, the two main problems I had was recognising the first equation $e^{t \hat{\mu}_n} = (M(\frac{t}{n-1}))^n$. Once I had that I was nearly there but would you believe when I arrived at the final answer I didn't recognise it as a variation of the Gaussian MGF. So I had the correct answer before you posted. I have a lot to learn!